# MVC5 Cannot return custom 404 error with JsonResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, http-status-code-404, jsonresult

I cannot return custom json result like below when I publish the MVC5+Angular2 project into IIS. Always return default IIS 404 error html.

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
return Json(myErrorObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Everything works fine whil developing project using IIS Express.

Thanks.

Comment: You dont have comma , here ?? Json(myErrorObject JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Thank you , I edited but it is not the problem. Problem is it is working with IIS Express but not IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return json with custom 404 or another http message, you need to set config like below;

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```